# click on AdvancedDataGrid cell and change its color

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

simple (?) question: what's the easiest way to programmatically change the style of an ADG cell most recently clicked by the user? Important note: I'm assuming cells not to editable and the selection mode to be singleRow, i.e. the specific cell needs to render differently from the standard highlight that comes with being part of the selected line.

I've found [this great article](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/using-an-itemrenderer-to-change-the-background-of-a-datagrid-cell/) that gets me pretty close, but I'm a bit stuck.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - I figured it out. I listen to the itemClick event on the ADG to figure out which cell has been clicked on, and then tweaked the code from the article above to only color the cell that has been clicked on.